# Why can't I unmask mongod.service?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, service, ubuntu-18.04, systemctl

Running `sudo service mongod start` yields `Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service is masked.`

Running `systemctl list-unit-files` indeed shows

```
mongod.service                                                            masked         
mongodb.service                                                           enabled
```

Running `sudo systemctl unmask mongod` gives no errors, but does not change anything either.

I checked for a symlink at `file /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` but it is `empty`.

I also tried removing `mongod.service` and recreating it.

Does anyone have any advice on what else to try?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this issue?

Comment: never did.. the project (and the computer it ran on) were abandoned for other reasons.